# Group the same ticket prices with Grade

Tags: php, arrays

I have output from my select query like below

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [TicketPrice] => 80
        [Grade] => O-1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [TicketPrice] => 80
        [Grade] => O-2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [TicketPrice] => 80
        [Grade] => O-3
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [TicketPrice] => 90
        [Grade] => O-4
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [TicketPrice] => 70
        [Grade] => O-5
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [TicketPrice] => 80
        [Grade] => G-1
    )
[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [TicketPrice] => 90
        [Grade] => G-2
    )
[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [TicketPrice] => 90
        [Grade] => G-2
    )
```

I need output Like I mention Below

1.O-1 to O-3 Price is 80 
 2.0-4 is 90 
 3.G-2 to G-2 price is 90

Answer (score 0):

You do like this,

```
SELECT TicketPrice, Grade FROM table_name WHERE [ conditions ] GROUP BY TicketPrice;
```

Comment: I want same ticket price like 0-1 to 0-3 price is 80. In your query its not showing 0-3 if we group ticektprice

Comment: This will help you..
SELECT TicketPrice, Grade FROM table_name WHERE [ conditions ] GROUP BY SUBSTR(Grade,1,1),TicketPrice;

Comment: Sorry...in this also i am not getting exact results